# Getting confidence intervals for robust regression coefficient (MASS::rlm)

Tags: r, statistics, mass

Is there any possible way to get 95% CI for regression coefficients from the robust regression, as implemented in MASS::rlm?

```r
# libraries needed
library(MASS)
library(stats)
library(datasets)

# running robust regression
(x <-
  MASS::rlm(formula = scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width),
            data = iris))
#> Call:
#> rlm(formula = scale(Sepal.Length) ~ scale(Sepal.Width), data = iris)
#> Converged in 5 iterations
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>        (Intercept) scale(Sepal.Width) 
#>        -0.03728607        -0.14343268 
#> 
#> Degrees of freedom: 150 total; 148 residual
#> Scale estimate: 1.06

# getting confidence interval for the regression coefficient
stats::confint(object = x,
               parm = "scale(Sepal.Width)",
               level = 0.95)
#>                    2.5 % 97.5 %
#> scale(Sepal.Width)    NA     NA
```

Comment: `confint.default(object = x, parm = "scale(Sepal.Width)", level = 0.95)`?

Comment: Woot! That worked! Had no idea there are two different functions called `stats::confint` and `stats::confint.default`. Can you post this as answer so that I can accept it? Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Explicitly calling `confint.default` seems to provide good results, like this:

```
confint.default(object = x, parm = "scale(Sepal.Width)", level = 0.95)

#                        2.5 %     97.5 %
#scale(Sepal.Width) -0.3058138 0.01894847
```

---

#### Edit

`confint` uses method `confint.lm` when it is passed `x`  because `x` is of class `lm` (as well as `rlm`). Calling `confint.default` explicitly avoids this. These two functions only differ in one line of code, as shown below:

### confint.lm

```
fac <- qt(a, object$df.residual)
```

### confint.default

```
fac <- qnorm(a)
```

The issue is that `x$df.residual` is `NA` and, consequently, `qt(a, object$df.residual)` produces an `NA` whereas `qnorm(a)` doesn't have this problem.

Comment: Any thoughts on why the exact same call works with the function `confint.default` but not `confint`?

Answer (score 1):

Late to the party, but note that CIs from the normal distribution will have lower than expected coverage for small sample sizes.

The residual degrees of freedom for the rlm object can be gotten from,

```
summary(x)$df[2]  # see code for MASS:::summary.rlm
```

To write your own confint method for rlm results, assign the df to the df.residual slot, and then call confint.lm:

```
confint.rlm <- function(object, ...){
  object$df.residual <- MASS:::summary.rlm(object)$df[2]
  confint.lm(object, ...)
}
```

Now confint behaves as expected, and is also based on Student's t:

```
confint(x)
                        2.5 %     97.5 %
(Intercept)        -0.2004593 0.12588715
scale(Sepal.Width) -0.3071526 0.02028719
```